# Giant RC Ground Effect Vehicle: How to determine the thrust required for takeoff from water

Tags: ground-effect, rc-aircraft, flying-boat

I am an aerospace engineering student, trying to design a large ground effect vehicle (GEV), and need advice/help to decide the thrust required for it to takeoff from the water surface.
[image: top view]
The model looks similar to the GEV in the following videos (It has a reverse delta wing and a flying boat style fuselage, with a large horizontal stabilizer):

and

The specifications for the model that I am designing are as follows:
Total Weight (including batteries): 16.28 kg,
Wing span = 2.3 m,
Wing area = 2.281 sq. m,
Wing Loading = 7.14 kg/sq. m,
Aspect Ratio = 2.32,
Estimated Cruise speed = 16 m/s.

It was suggested to me that, as a rule of thumb, a power-to-weight ratio of 170 W/kg is required for take-off from water. I want to ask what is the minimum amount of thrust that will be needed for this model to takeoff and fly (if high performance is not a requirement)
How do I calculate the thrust required (or what kind of motors I need) for this model to takeoff from water and fly?

Thank you

Comment: A lot depends on the location and shape of the step on the bottom of the fuselage relative to the center of gravity.

Comment: I have designed the step to be 8-9% of the beam and the Centre of Gravity is to be slightly ahead of the step (on a line 10 degree to the vertical at step). I used this based on the book "RC Model Aircraft Design" by Andy Lennon.

Comment: I once did take-off calculations for the Dornier Seastar and remember that there is a tradeoff with a rear step which allows for a smaller angle while planing, causing less drag while going over the hump and a more forward step which better allows to rotate for liftoff. Generally, thrust required over the hump increases with the keeling angle. That is the reason why early seaplanes had a flat bottom. However, keeling improves ride quality when planing in rough seas.

Comment: There were designs with several and retractable steps. A retractable step reduces drag in flight but also combines the benefits of a more forward and a more backward step when used properly.
I guess I cannot improve on the advice you got from books, so I post this as a comment rather than an answer which my rant clearly isn't.